# SonarQube pipeline error while configuring gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: php, gitlab, sonarqube, pipeline, cicd

I would like to add SonarQube code analyzer to our pipeline process, but I got this error, when trying to insert Sonarqube config (code below at "sonarqube-check" section) to the GitLab repo's gitlab-ci.yml file:
"This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:deploy_prod config contains unknown keys: sonarqube-check"

The whole gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
#CI/CD
stages:
  - deploy

deploy_test:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    #some code here
  when: manual
  only:
    - develop
  tags:
    - commoncode

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    #some code here
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - commoncode

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    #some code here
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - commoncode

sonarqube-check:
 image: 
   name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
   entrypoint: [""]
 variables:
   SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
   GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task
 cache:
   key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
   paths:
     - .sonar/cache
 script: 
   - sonar-scanner
 allow_failure: true
 only:
   - master
```

Could you help me to make yml to become valid?